# unable to pass navigation props b/w screens with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

In my component `ContactList`, I have rendered sone items using a map. Each item contains a thumbnail. When I click on the thumbnail, I want to navigate to a new screen called `UserDetailsScreen`. While I navigate, I also want to transfer data to the next screen about the particular user whose thumbnail was clicked on.

Modals don't work properly since multiple modals will open if I used it in a map. So I am trying to use react-navigation.

ContactList.tsx:

```
export const ContactList: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({
  data,
  onDeleteContact,
}) => {
  const [isUserVisible, setIsUserVisible] = useState(false);
  //const [visibleUser, setVisibleUser] = useState<any>();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={styles.users}>
      {data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(
        (item: { relatedUser: RelatedUser; id: number }) => {
          const numberOfFriends = item.relatedUser.userRelations.length;
          const numberPlate = 'WHV AB 123';
          return (
            <View style={styles.item} key={item.id}>
              {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsUserVisible(true)}> */}
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate('UserDetailsScreen', {
                    firstName: item.relatedUser.firstName,
                    rating: item.relatedUser.rating,
                    numberOfFriends: numberOfFriends,
                    onDeleteContact: onDeleteContact,
                    isUserVisible: isUserVisible,
                    setIsUserVisible: setIsUserVisible,
                    numberPlate: numberPlate,
                    navigation: navigation,
                  })
                }>
                <Thumbnail
                  }}></Thumbnail>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={styles.nameNumber}>
                <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
              </View>
              {/* <UserDetails
                firstName={item.relatedUser.firstName}
                rating={item.relatedUser.rating}
                numberOfFriends={numberOfFriends}
                onDeleteContact={onDeleteContact}
                isUserVisible={isUserVisible}
                setIsUserVisible={setIsUserVisible}
                  numberPlate={numberPlate}>
                </UserDetails> */}
            </View>
          );
        },
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

UserDetailsScreen:

```
type UserProps = {
  //data: UsersQueryHookResult,
  firstName: string;
  rating: number;
  numberOfFriends: number;
  numberPlate: string;
  onDeleteContact: (id: number) => void;
  navigation: any;
};

export const UserDetailsScreen: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({
  firstName,
  rating,
  numberOfFriends,
  numberPlate,
  onDeleteContact,
  navigation,
//   isUserVisible,
//   setIsUserVisible,
}) => {
//const navigation = useNavigation();
const fName = navigation.getParam('firstName')
  return (
    // <Modal visible={isUserVisible}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.cross}
            //onPress={() => setIsUserVisible(false)}>
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Whitelist')}>
            <Thumbnail></Thumbnail>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.searchLocationContainer}>
          <UserInfoContainer
            firstName={firstName}
            rating={rating}
            numberPlate={numberPlate}
            numberOfFriends={numberOfFriends}></UserInfoContainer>
        </View>
      </View>
    // </Modal>
  );
};
```

Additionally, when I click on the thumbnail from this screen, I should go back to my previous screen such that I can click on another object now.

For now, I keep getting an error that `navigation.getParam` is undefined. How can I fix this?

I believe I need to pass the `route` props but I'm not sure how to use them and whether I should pass them in both screens or one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get data from route props

like

```
type UserProps = {
  //data: UsersQueryHookResult,
  firstName: string;
  rating: number;
  numberOfFriends: number;
  numberPlate: string;
  onDeleteContact: (id: number) => void;
  navigation: any;
  route: any;
};

export const UserDetailsScreen: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({
  firstName,
  rating,
  numberOfFriends,
  numberPlate,
  onDeleteContact,
  navigation,
  route,
//   isUserVisible,
//   setIsUserVisible,
})....
```

```
route.params.firstName
```

if you can navigate to `UserDetailsScreen` then you don't need to pass any route. because navigation and it's property are set with `UserDetailsScreen`

Comment: If I use ```const fName = props.route.params.firstName;``` in my ```UserDetailsScreen```, I get an error that ```Cannot find name 'props'.```. I don't really get what props to pass and how. I'm already using ```UserProps```

Comment: because you have object as porps
define a route in that

Comment: How will I pass route from the ```ContactList``` screen? ```route: route```? But there's no route variable. If possible could you help me by making edits in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your method of passing the params to UserDetailsScreen is correct.

In the previous version of react-navigation(1.x to 4.x) you can get params in "navigation.state.params".

In react-navigation 5 they have changed its implementation. Now you can get params passed to your screen or component in "route.params" Object. You can check the code for reference below.

```
type UserProps = {
route: any,
navigation: any,
};

export const UserDetailsScreen: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({
route,navigation
}) => {
const {
    firstname,
    rating,
    numberOfFriends,
    numberPlate,
    onDeleteContact,
} = route.params;
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.cross}
        //onPress={() => setIsUserVisible(false)}>
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Whitelist')}>
        <Thumbnail />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.searchLocationContainer}>
        <UserInfoContainer
        firstName={firstName}
        rating={rating}
        numberPlate={numberPlate}
        numberOfFriends={numberOfFriends}
        />
    </View>
    </View>
);
};
```

Comment: do you know what is the actual type of ```route```? Using any is not ideal.